# Why can't I get info one both two Spring "many-to-many" entities after association via PUT/PATCH route?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, many-to-many

I'm trying to use a many-to-many association and spring to associate an existing worker with an existing task but when I use the PUT/PATCH route can't get any data back from (only) those items using either GET /tasks/{taskId} or GET /dev/{devId}.

Here are the two models. The Workers model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Workers")
public class Worker implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String workerName;
    private String passwd;

    @RestResource(path = "/assocTask")
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "tasks_workers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "worker_id",  referencedColumnName = "id",nullable = false, updatable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false))
    //@JsonManagedReference
    private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    public Worker() {
    }

    public Worker(String name, String password) {
        this.workerName = name;
        this.passwd = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return workerName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.workerName = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return passwd;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.passwd = password;
    }

    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Worker{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", workerName='" + workerName + '\'' +
                ", passwd='" + passwd + '\'' +
                ", tasks=" + tasks +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and the task model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tasks")
public class Task implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tasks", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();

    public Task() {
    }

    public Task(@NotNull String title, @NotNull String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


    public List<Worker> getWorkers() {
        return workers;
    }

    public void setWorkers(List<Worker> workers) {
        this.workers = workers;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", workers=" + workers +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting if I GET /tasks/1, for example:

```
Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate java.util.Optional.toString()
```

coming from the service implementation to get it from the DB:

```
    @Override
public Task getTaskById(Long taskId) throws TaskNotFoundException {
    if (taskId == null || taskId < 0) {
        LOGGER.error("Invalid params received");
        throw new Error("INVALID_ID");
    }

    return taskRepository.findById(taskId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new TaskNotFoundException(taskId, messageSource));
}
```

And this is the query that is executed by hibernate:

```
select
    tasks0_.worker_id as worker_id1_2_0_,
    tasks0_.task_id as task_id2_2_0_,
    task1_.id as id1_1_1_,
    task1_.description as descript2_1_1_,
    task1_.title as title5_1_1_ 
from
    tasks_workers tasks0_ 
inner join
    tasks task1_ 
        on tasks0_.task_id=task1_.id 
where
    tasks0_.worker_id=?
```

If I run it in Postgres I get the results as expected...
Seems like it is looping infinitely... But what is causing the overflow and why doesn't it happen before the association or after breaking it?

Any ideas?

Comment: It does! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Is a `StackOverflowError` with the information that it happens in the `toString` method not obvious enough to you to figure out the issue? Assume you call `Worker.toString()` on the worker with id 1. In `Worker.toString()` you call `List.toString()` on `tasks` which for every `Task` calls `Task.toString()`. In `Task.toString()` you then call `List.toString()` on `workers` which is where you enter your infinite recursion because every `Task` that is connected to `Worker` is part of the `tasks` list and also the other way round, every `Worker` that is connected to `Task` is part of the `workers` list. This is a cyclic object graph.

The simple solution, just don't call `toString()` on collections that might have a back-reference. Or decide who is the "owner" and only call `toString` on the owning side.

Comment: Actually that was one of the problems but not the full sollution. Needed to remove the toString() methods out of the constructor and also needed to add two new annotations:@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id") //prevents recursions in the Workers model and @JsonIgnore to the linked column in the Tasks model. After some testing I found that I could also refactor the toSring() methods in each model and no recursivness occurs. None the less I appreciate the kindness "not obvious enough to you to figure out the issue"...

Comment: I'm sorry if that offends you, but this is such a common usage error for which a Stackoverflow question was asked many times before, that I also could have just requested to close your question. If you had used the search function, you would have found solutions and explanations like the one I provided you.